# How do I respond to a get request with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How do I respond to a get request with Flask? I found nothing in the documentation, I find it hard to understand, I've also searched online and found nothing.

I have a form here's part of the code:

```
<input type="radio" name="topic" value="{{ topic }}" id="{{ topic }}" onclick="submit()">
```

Now as you can see from this, the input sends the value of 'topic' when submitted.

How can I use Flask to respond to any GET request like that input? Something like this:

```
@app.route('/topic/[any 'topic' value from form]', methods=['GET'])
def topic():
    topic = request.form['topic']
    return render_template('topic.html', topic=topic)
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:

So I decided to use post as suggested. I tried to test post with this code:

```
@app.route('/topic/', methods=['POST'])
def topic():
    chosenTopic = request.form['chosenTopic']
    return render_template('topic.html', chosenTopic=chosenTopic)
```

and this form:

```
<input type="radio" name="chosenTopic" value="{{ topic[3:topic|length-4:] }}" id="chosenTopic" onclick="submit()">
```

I tested it out on the /topic page with a simple {{ chosenTopic }} but nothing appears? Does anyone have any suggestions as to why?

Comment: What do you mean by any topic from form?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Your endpoint value contains [any 'topic' value from form]. Are you asking how to include input from the form in the request URL?

Comment: Yeah that's right it's just to show what I want, however I'm not sure its correct syntax

Comment: Also consider why you're using GET to submit form data and not POST.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about it, I've read this section, I tried putting it like this: @app.route('/topic/<topic>', methods=['GET']) because I assigned the request.form['topic'] to topic so I thought it would work but no. What can I do?

Comment: I've considered GET over POST because I need the user to see the topic in the url, otherwise it won't be clear but if I must then I guess I'd have to choose POST if GET won't suffice.

Comment: You can accept the parameters in a POST request and after that redirect to a GET with the required url. Its a very common pattern on the web.

Comment: You mean if I was to replace methods with POST it would work the same? If not could you please show me how to write the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this shows a simple example.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

# really look in db here or do whatever you need to do to validate this as a valid topic.
def is_valid_topic(topic):
    if topic == "foo":
        return False
    else:
        return True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<html><form action="topic/" method="post"><input name="topic" type="text"><input type="submit"/></form></html>'

@app.route('/topic/', methods=['POST'])
def find_topic():
    t = request.form['topic']
    if is_valid_topic(t):
        return redirect('topic/%s' % t)
    else:
        return "404 error INVALID TOPIC", 404

@app.route('/topic/<topic>')
def show_topic(topic):
    if is_valid_topic(topic):
        return '''<html><h1>The topic is %s</h1></html>''' % topic
    else:
        return "404 error INVALID TOPIC", 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You accept the params in a POST request and redirect to the GET afterwards.

Comment: Thank you this is brilliant! Appreciate the help however I have one more question. Say I wanted to use POST to send something when an image is clicked how would I go about that because I'm not using a form?

Comment: Put it in a new question.

Comment: and accept and upvote if its the answer you were after:)